# Matlab synchronize Timetables with logical content

Tags: matlab, synchronize, timetable

I'm trying to synchronize different timetables in Matlab. These timetables contain machine Data, so there are some rows with doubles, but also integer, categorical and bool.

When I try to synchronize, I get the error,

"All variables in input timetables must support missing values (e.g. floating point, categorical, datetime, duration, or text) when synchronizing using 'default'."

I think this is happening, because there is no NaN in logical arrays, is it?

Any ideas how I can still synchronize these timetables?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show a code example that generates this error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the default fill method with `logical` data. (The error message does hint at this, but it doesn't quite tell you how to fix it). I think you need something like this:

```
tt1 = timetable(datetime(2018,11,1), true, 3.0)
tt2 = timetable(datetime(2018,11,2), false, 4.0)
synchronize(tt1, tt2, 'union', 'fillwithconstant')
```

The key piece here is the `'fillwithconstant'` part for the ["method"](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/synchronize.html#bvdhiyk-method) - other methods are available.